# Difficulties proving that integral contribution over semi-circle vanishes

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Using complex analysis theory I am trying to evaluate following integral over a contour consisting of the real axis and a semi circle:

$\int_{0}^{\infty } \frac{x sin(\pi x)}{1-x^2}dx$

This can be rewritten as:

$\frac{1}{4i}\left (\int_{-\infty}^{\infty } \frac{z e^{\pi z}}{1-z^2}dz-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty } \frac{z e^{-\pi z}}{1-z^2}dz  \right )$

Using the upper semi-circle $C_{R_{+}}$ and making small detours for the singularities which are on the real axis I get that if $\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\left (\int_{C_{R_{+}}}^{ } \frac{z e^{\pi z}}{1-z^2}dz  \right )=0$ the following holds:

$\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\left (\int_{-R}^{R } \frac{z e^{\pi z}}{1-z^2}dz+\int_{C_{R_{+}}}^{ } \frac{z e^{\pi z}}{1-z^2}dz  \right )=2\pi i\left (\underset{z=1}{Res}\frac{z e^{\pi z}}{1-z^2}  + \underset{z=-1}{Res}\frac{z e^{\pi z}}{1-z^2} \right )=2\pi i$

However, I have difficulties proving that $\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\left (\int_{C_{R_{+}}}^{ } \frac{z e^{\pi z}}{1-z^2}dz  \right )=0$ holds and can therefore not verify whether I can calculate the integral using these residues.

I aim to use Jordan's lemma which implies:

If $\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}max|\frac{z}{1-z^2}|=0$ then $\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\left (\int_{C_{R_{+}}}^{ } \frac{z e^{\pi z}}{1-z^2}dz  \right )=0$

Now:

$max|\frac{z}{1-z^2}|=max|\frac{R e^{i \theta}}{1-R^2 e^{i 2 \theta}}|=\frac{R}{1-R^2}$

$\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\frac{R}{1-R^2}=0$

Is this the correct way to prove that $\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\left (\int_{C_{R_{+}}}^{ } \frac{z e^{\pi z}}{1-z^2}dz  \right )=0$?

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo, presumably you meant to have $i$ in the exponents.

Assuming such, you cannot get a nice result by using $2i\sin(z)=e^{iz}-e^{-iz}$, as this grows exponentially as $z\to\pm i\infty$. Instead you want to use $\sin(z)=\Im(e^{iz})$ to get

\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x\sin(\pi x)}{1-x^2}~\mathrm dx&=\Im\left({\rm P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{xe^{i\pi x}}{1-x^2}~\mathrm dx\right)\\&=\lim_{R\to\infty,\epsilon\to0}\Im\left(\oint_{C(\epsilon,R)}-\int_{C_1(\epsilon)}-\int_{C_2(\epsilon)}-\int_{C_3(R)}\right)\\&=\Im\left(0+\pi i\mathop{\rm Res}_{z=-1}+\pi i\mathop{\rm Res}_{z=1}+0\right)\\&=\pi\end{align}

where $C=C_1\cup C_2\cup C_3\cup(-R,-\epsilon)\cup(\epsilon,R)$ and $C_1,C_2,C_3$ are semicircles around $z=-1,1,0$ respectively.

As the integrand is holomorphic in $C$, it evaluates to zero.

The integrals over $C_1$ and $C_2$ tend to $\pi i$ times their residues.

The integral over $C_3$ tends to zero by Jordan's lemma.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sin z=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$, you have, in fact, that $\sin(\pi z)=\frac{e^{i\pi z}-e^{-i\pi z}}{2i}$. Therefore, your contour integral should be$$\int_{C_{R_+}}\frac{ze^{i\pi z}}{1-z^2}\,\mathrm dz.$$Can you take it from here?